# Cannot install head plugin using bin/plugin tool (elasticsearch)

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, proxy, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-head

I have just downloaded [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch) and I am trying to grab the [head plugin](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head)

First I try this

```
sudo bin/plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head --verbose
```

I get the error

```
Trying https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head/archive/master.zip ...
Failed: UnknownHostException[github.com]
```

Now I try and add a few command line parameters

```
sudo bin/plugin -DproxyUser=<my proxy user> -DproxyPassword=<my proxy password> -DproxyHost=<my proxy user> -DproxyPort=<my proxy port> install mobz/elasticsearch-head --verbose
```

Now I get the error

```
Trying https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head/archive/master.zip ...
Failed: IOException[Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"]
```

Anyone have any advice here? I'm trying to use the tool that comes with elasticsearch, rather than go grab the plugin manually and plop it in the plugins folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to specify proxy info such as host and port in the parameter. Check this documentation.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/_other_command_line_parameters.html#_proxy_settings

Comment: This was indeed the issue. I had forgotten that I asked this. But essentially, the command needed the proxyPort as well as the proxyHost. We had changed proxies recently at the office, which is why it was getting messed up.